# Unable to install cubature package (configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables)

Tags: r, macos, terminal, compiler-errors, homebrew

I've been trying to install the "statsr" package for the "Stats with R" specialization on coursera, however, I've run into quite a few roadblocks here.

After trying everything suggested on StackOverflow and otherwise, this is where I'm at.

Apparently, I'm unable to install the "curbature" package without which "statsr" wouldn't install.

```
> install_local("~/Downloads//statsr-master")
```

Statsr error: https://pastebin.com/8wGequDQ

```
> install.packages("cubature")
```

Curbature error : https://pastebin.com/MLb4Dqf3

I have command line tools installed along with clang and gcc. Brew config log shown below :

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.0.2
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew 
HEAD: 117c24f4b6294e037431d3a850ced6955d53e26f
Last commit: 6 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 912d73ae0e5e38162e1dce53e5a53bb060d78da8
Core tap last commit: 9 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_LOGS: /Users/shaileshdudala/Library/Logs/Homebrew
CPU: dodeca-core 64-bit kabylake
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.7 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 10.0 build 1000
Git: 2.17.2 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 11.0.2
macOS: 10.14-x86_64
CLT: 10.1.0.0.1.1539992718
Xcode: 10.1
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I had the same issue. Uninstalled RStudio from Anaconda, then installed RStudio *independently* (not through Anaconda) and ran all of the package install commands. Works fine now